# starting warden after zookeeper of MapR

Tags: apache-zookeeper, warden, mapr

I am installing the MapR and I stucked at starting warden after start zookeeper on a single node.

```
# service mapr-warden start
Error: warden can not be started. See /opt/mapr/logs/warden.log for details
```

On this file there is no detail. Does anybody have a hint? Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't getting anything in warden.log, then it's likely that the warden JVM is never even being started by the mapr-warden init script.

In some MapR versions, the mapr-warden init script will log some details into /opt/mapr/logs/wardeninit.log.  You can try checking there.

However, I will also caution that currently the logging done by the init script is sparse and not necessarily user friendly to read.  If you can't discern the cause from the contents of the wardeninit.log you can post them here and maybe I can help.

Another thing you can do is edit /etc/init.d/mapr-warden and add "set -x" towards the top of the file, right before the "BASEMAPR=" line, then try starting warden again and you'll get a bunch of shell debugging output on your screen.  If you copy and paste that output here that should be enough to tell the root cause of the problem.

One more thing to mention, you may be better off using the http://answers.mapr.com forum as that is MapR specific and I think there may be more users there that could help.

Comment: thanks, I post the question there: http://answers.mapr.com/questions/8722/error-starting-warden-on-mapr-single-node with another comments...

Answer (score 1):

Was configure.sh (/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C nodeA -Z nodeA)run on the node?  Did zookeeper come up successfully?

service mapr-zookeeper status

Comment: I am installing mapr-single-node to get how to play with mapr. I didn't configure anything at configure.sh. The zookeeper is right # /etc/init.d/mapr-zookeeper start
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/mapr/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.3.6/conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED

Comment: # service mapr-zookeeper status
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/mapr/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.3.6/conf/zoo.cfg
zookeeper running as process 17762.

Answer (score 0):

Even when using MapR in a single node configure.sh is still required. In fact, without configure.sh warden, zookeeper, cldb and other MapR components will lack their configuration and in many cases will fail to start.

You **must** run configure.sh after installing the software packages (deb or rpm).